# Getting error when using with keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server

> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 25
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

I am getting this error when I am using `WITH` keyword in `CASE` statement.

How can I solve that?

```
case 
    when 1 
    then I am with you 
    else I am not with you.
```

Comment: Also: `CASE` is T-SQL is **not** a statement (to control execution flow) - it's an **expression** to return one or another value only.

Answer (score 6):

you need to enclose strings in single quotes `'like so'`

```
case when 1 = 1 
    then 'I am with you' 
    else 'I am not with you.'
END
```

As it currently stands, SQL is trying to interpret "I", "am", "with", and "you" as commands/keywords/whatevers, when they are actually part of a string.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the 1 after when, no need to put 1=1 :

**case 
    when 1 
    then 'I am with you' 
    else 'I am not with you.' end**

Comment: I think this would depend on the RDBMS, in sql-server `case when 1 then...` is not valid - gives error `Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'then'.`